# Converting an abbreviation found in multiple strings to the full word - PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, abbreviation

I am trying to manipulate a multiple strings in PHP. I am extracting array data using `foreach` loops and `if statements`. Some of the array data is stored as abbreviations. I want to convert these abbreviations to the full word. One example is the abbreviation `pwr` which stands for `power`. The abbreviation can be found in a variety of different contexts. Below I will attach my PHP code followed by its respective output where you can see the variety of strings the `pwr` abbreviation can be found in.

PHP:

```
<?php

foreach ($finaltitle as $titlenumber => $titlename){
 foreach ($techData as $tsnumber => $tsname){
  if ($tsnumber == $titlenumber){
    if(empty($tsname) or $tsname === '- TBD -') continue;

    $finaltsdata = "<b>".$titlename." (".$tsnumber.") "."</b>: ".strtolower($tsname)."<br>";
    echo $finaltsdata;
  }
 }
}

?>
```

Output:

```
Suspension Type - Front (105) : 4-link,
Suspension Type - Rear (106) : trapezoidal link,
Suspension Type - Front (Cont.) (107) : pwr-adjustable sport
Suspension Type - Rear (Cont.) (108) : pwr-adjustable sport
Front Tire Size (140) : p235/40yr18
Rear Tire Size (141) : p235/40yr18
Spare Tire Size (142) : p235/40yr18
Front Wheel Size (156) : 18 x 8.0
Rear Wheel Size (157) : 18 x 8.0
Spare Wheel Size (158) : 18 x 8.0
Front Wheel Material (165) : alloy
Rear Wheel Material (166) : alloy
Spare Wheel Material (167) : alloy
Steering Type (176) : pwr rack & pinion
Steering Ratio (:1), Overall (178) : 16.3
Turning Diameter - Curb to Curb (184) : 37.7
Brake Type (186) : pwr
```

Notice how the abbreviation `pwr` can be found in a variety of different contexts: alone, before a set of words, before a dash, etc. How can I create a statement within my `foreach` code to convert all mentions of `pwr` to `power`?

Thanks!

---

```
$array = [
 '/\b(pwr|Pwr|powr)\b/i' => 'power',
];

$tsname = preg_replace(array_keys($array), $array);


foreach ($finaltitle as $titlenumber => $titlename){
 foreach ($techData as $tsnumber => $tsname){   
  if ($tsnumber == $titlenumber){
    if(empty($tsname) or $tsname === '- TBD -') continue;
    $finaltsdata = "<b>".$titlename." (".$tsnumber.") "."</b>: ".$tsname."<br>";
    echo $finaltsdata;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Try using str_replace : `strtolower(str_replace('pwr', 'power', $tsname))`

Comment: I would use preg_replace because it allows you to use word boundary such as `/\bpwr\b/`   I would make an array like this `['/\bpwr\b/' => 'power']` and then use `preg_replace(array_keys($array), $array)` simple and you can add on more `pattern => replacements` really easy..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comments

```
 $array = [
    '/\bpwr\b/i' => 'power',
    '/\bbrk\b/i' => 'brake'
 ];


 $str = preg_replace(array_keys($array), $array, $str);
```

Then you just add more words and their replacement.  Preg Replace is better because you can use `\b` or the word boundary which prevents things like matching `pwr` in `pwrstr` or what have you.  The `\b` matches `\W` or not `\w` or in english (lol)  anything not `a-z` `A-Z` `0-9` and `_`.

String replace could match a part of a word, which you don't really want to take the chance on.

One other advantage of preg_replace is this `\b(pwr|powr)\b` where you could match both of these and replace them with the same thing.  The `()` is a capture group, here I use it just to group the words so the `\b` doesn't have to be repeated.  And the `|` is OR.

The last thing is you can use the `i` flag (after the ending delimiter `/foo/i`) to make it case insensitive.  With `str_ireplace()`, you can do the same, but you can't differentiate on a per match basis like you can with `preg_replace()`.

Both work with arrays so you don't have to loop over the multiple replacement yourself with either `str_repace()` or `preg_replace()`.

If you need help, or just to test the Regular Expressions, this site is one of the best test Regex site around https://regex101.com/  (IMO).  That said, there are some slight difference (probably nothing you'll notice), but another good site is this one http://preg_replace.onlinephpfunctions.com/ . If you look at the navigation on it, it has a bunch of PHP sandboxy stuff.

Cheers!

Comment: Could just use a link to the manual... http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I really like this mainly because I wouldn't want to match part of a word like you mentioned. I updated the bottom of the question with my revised code. Still isn't fully functioning for me but I will keep tweaking until it does. Thanks!

Comment: @mugelloblue also to note that the [`/i` pattern modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) makes the pattern case-insensitive. so `a` will also match `A`.

Comment: @mugelloblue - I forgot the 3rd argument, which is the subject string to do the replacement on.  Plus you'll probably (maybe) have to work it into your loop(s), I couldn't really tell where to put it in you code without more context about what some of the $variables mean.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix right before you commented that I added the third argument and it worked great! Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, have a good night (well it's night here at least).  Time for me to head home...